# MYSQL error in 'unknown column in having clause'

Tags: mysql

the query is as follows and i get the error:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM author a, catalog c
WHERE a.authorid = c.authorid
AND c.bookid IN (
    SELECT bookid
    FROM orderdetails
    GROUP BY bookid
    HAVING sum(quantity) = (
        SELECT max(sum(quantity))
        FROM orderdetails
    )
);
```

The following tables are maintained by a book dealer.

```
AUTHOR (author-id:int, name:string, city:string, country:string)
PUBLISHER (publisher-id:int, name:string, city:string, country:string)
CATALOG (book-id:int, title:string, author-id:int, publisher-id:int, category-id:int, year:int, price:int)
CATEGORY (category-id:int, description:string)
ORDER-DETAILS (order-no:int, book-id:int, quantity:int)
```

and question is:

iv. Find the author of the book which has maximum sales.

Comment: Tip: you don't have to write SQL code in one statement. You can use carriage returns and indentation as with any other kind of code. See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 0):

could be you need a intermediate group by

```
  select a.name 
  from author a
  inner join catalog c on  a.authorid=c.authorid 
  and c.bookid in (select bookid 
            from orderdetails 
            group by bookid 
            having sum(quantity) = (
                select max( sum_quantity) from (
                  select sum(quantity) sum_quantity
                  from orderdetails 
                  group by bookid 
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error, because the having is only on columns you have selected :

```
SELECT a.name
FROM author a, catalog c
WHERE a.authorid = c.authorid
AND c.bookid IN (
    SELECT bookid, sum(quantity) as total_qty
    FROM orderdetails
    GROUP BY bookid
    HAVING total_qty = (
        SELECT max(sum(quantity))
        FROM orderdetails
    )
);
```

I think you can avoid the IN which is better to try to get a less heavy query :

```
 SELECT a.name
    FROM author a
    INNER JOIN catalog c ON  a.authorid = c.authorid
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT bookid, sum(quantity) as total_qty
        FROM orderdetails
        GROUP BY bookid
        HAVING total_qty = (
          SELECT max(sum(quantity))
          FROM orderdetails
        )
     ) t ON t.bookid = c.bookid
```